# Why does svg alignment change when parent div is < 14px in size?

Tags: html, css, svg, alignment

I want the svg to be the same width/height as the parent div.

I've created a reduced test case below of a simple svg inside a div:

```
<div class="box">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
       viewBox="0 0 50 50">
    <rect width="50" height="50"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Changing the parent width/height will change the size of the svg:

```
.box {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

When the parent div width/height is less than 14px, the svg is no longer aligned inside the div. **Why is this the case?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To understand the issue add some text inside and use different font-sizes:

```css
.box {
  height: 30px;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  background-color: red;
  margin:5px;
}
svg {
  width:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  A
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
       viewBox="0 0 50 50">
    <rect width="50" height="50"/>
  </svg>
</div>

<div class="box" style="font-size:30px;">
  A
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
       viewBox="0 0 50 50">
    <rect width="50" height="50"/>
  </svg>
</div>

<div class="box" style="font-size:40px;">
  A
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
       viewBox="0 0 50 50">
    <rect width="50" height="50"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

You can clearly see that the SVG is aligned with the baseline of the text and if the font-size is growing you will have an overflow. Same logic if we keep the same font-size and we decrease the height:

```css
.box {
  height: 40px;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  background-color: red;
  margin:5px;
}
svg {
  width:40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  A
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
       viewBox="0 0 50 50">
    <rect width="50" height="50"/>
  </svg>
</div>

<div class="box" style="height:20px;">
  A
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
       viewBox="0 0 50 50" style="width:20px;">
    <rect width="50" height="50"/>
  </svg>
</div>

<div class="box" style="height:10px;">
  A
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
       viewBox="0 0 50 50" style="width:10px;">
    <rect width="50" height="50"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

And if you remove the text, the behavior will be kept the same since the baseline won't change:

```css
.box {
  height: 40px;
  width:40px;
  display:inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  margin:5px;
  padding:2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
       viewBox="0 0 50 50">
    <rect width="50" height="50"/>
  </svg>
</div>

<div class="box" style="height:20px;width:20px;">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
       viewBox="0 0 50 50">
    <rect width="50" height="50"/>
  </svg>
</div>

<div class="box" style="height:10px;width:10px;">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
       viewBox="0 0 50 50">
    <rect width="50" height="50"/>
  </svg>
</div>

<div class="box" style="height:5px;width:5px;">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
       viewBox="0 0 50 50">
    <rect width="50" height="50"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

To avoid this, simply adjust the alignment and make it different from baseline:

```css
.box {
  height: 20px;
  width:20px;
  display:inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  margin:5px;
  padding:2px;
}

svg {
 vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
       viewBox="0 0 50 50">
    <rect width="50" height="50"/>
  </svg>
</div>

<div class="box" style="height:10px;width:10px;">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
       viewBox="0 0 50 50">
    <rect width="50" height="50"/>
  </svg>
</div>

<div class="box" style="height:5px;width:5px;">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
       viewBox="0 0 50 50">
    <rect width="50" height="50"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Or reset the font-size to 0:

```css
.box {
  height: 20px;
  width:20px;
  display:inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  margin:5px;
  padding:2px;
  font-size:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
       viewBox="0 0 50 50">
    <rect width="50" height="50"/>
  </svg>
</div>

<div class="box" style="height:10px;width:10px;">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
       viewBox="0 0 50 50">
    <rect width="50" height="50"/>
  </svg>
</div>

<div class="box" style="height:5px;width:5px;">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
       viewBox="0 0 50 50">
    <rect width="50" height="50"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```